# Learning Pascal FC

Tags: pascal, pascal-fc

I'm looking for tutorials and examples on Pascal FC's channels and rendesvouz mechanisms.

Comment: There are some samples here http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/burns/pf.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a [nice introductory tutorial](http://blogjuan.com.ar/2009/01/introduccion-pascal-fc.html), but unluckily it is in Spanish.

You may also take a look at the language's [reference manual](http://www.lcc.uma.es/~gallardo/lrm.pdf) and [user guide](http://www.lcc.uma.es/~gallardo/pc_ug.pdf), but they are not suitable for learning the language from scratch.

I have not found any digital, freely accessible, introductory material in English yet.

I've been learning with a Spanish book on Concurrent Programming and there may be a bunch of books that explain topics on Concurrent Programming with Pascal-FC, but I have not checked them.

However, you might find the bibliographies of this papers useful:

1. [Teaching concurrent programming with Pascal-FC](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=126453)
2. [Pascal-FC: a language for teaching concurrent programming](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=44309)

You do not need to download the papers to see the bibliography, the list is shown on the webpage. However, there are some explanations and examples in the papers that might be useful to you, it would thus be nice if you could access those papers.

There is also another [thorough list of books on Concurrent Programming](http://www.uhu.es/josel_alvarez/Prog/programa.pdf) which you may want to have a look at if you are realy looking forward to learning Pascal-FC.

Comment: I have noticed that there are some examples in the channels section of Pascal-FC's reference manual, and there are a few other examples. You should check that.